# Spring Elasticsearch Aggregation Filtering Not Working

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I'm trying to query pricing stats on products I am recording in my Elasticsearch Database by product number.  The pricing may be for new, used or refurbished products, so I wish to filter on condition.  The condition filter works as a JSON query in Marvel returning stats based on two price documents with condition new.

When I try to do similar using the Java API, I am getting stats based on 4 documents that includes 2 new and 2 refurbished.

Could anyone please identify what I am doing wrong in the Java code below?

Thanks.

Here's the working JSON Query:

```
GET /stats/price/_search
{
  "query": {
  "match_phrase": {"mpc": "MGTX2LL/A"}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
      "low_price_stats" : { 
      "filter": {
          "term" : { "condition" : "new"}
      },
      "aggs" : {
          "price_stats" : { "extended_stats" : { "field" : "price" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the problematic Java:

```
public Aggregations aggByManufacturerPartNumber(String mpn) {

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withIndices("stats")
        .withTypes("price")
        .withQuery(termQuery("mpn", mpn))
        .withFilter(
            FilterBuilders.termFilter("condition", "New")
        )
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.extendedStats("stats_agg").field("price"))
        .build();

    Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
        @Override
        public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
            return response.getAggregations();
        }
    });

    return aggregations;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Java code you're only building the `price_stats` sub-aggregation without its parent `filter` aggregation. The call to `withFilter` will create a filter at the query level, not at the aggregation level. The correct Java code that matches your JSON query would be like this:

```
// build top-level filter aggregation
FilterAggregationBuilder lowPriceStatsAgg = AggregationBuilders.filter("low_price_stats")
    .filter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("condition", "new"));

// build extended stats sub-aggregation
lowPriceStatsAgg.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.extendedStats("stats_agg").field("price"));

// build query
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withIndices("stats")
    .withTypes("price")
    .withQuery(termQuery("mpn", mpn))
    .addAggregation(lowPriceStatsAgg)
    .build();

// then get the results
Aggregations aggs = response.getAggregations();
Filter lowPriceStats = aggs.get("low_price_stats");
ExtendedStats statsAgg = lowPriceStats.get("stats_agg");
```

Besides, also note that in your JSON query you have a `match_phrase` on the `mpc` field while in your Java code you have a `term` query on the `mpn` field. So you probably need to fix that, too, but the above code fixes the aggregation part only.

Comment: OK, Thanks!  I'm almost there.  The sub aggregation appears to be lowPriceStatsAgg.subAggregation(...).   I'm getting a null after the query and extractor.  Because it's a subAggregation, do I need to make a different ResultExtractor?